# In Scan EOF error while reading CSV file

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file into R. I tried:

```
data <- read.csv(file="train.csv")
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

But, this reads in only a small percentage of the total observations. Then I tried removing quotes:

```
 data <- read.csv(file="train.csv",quote = "",sep = ",",header = TRUE)
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

Since the data is text, it seems there is some issue with the delimiter.

It is difficult to share the entire data set as it is huge. I tried going to the line where the error comes, but there seems to be no non printable character. I also tried other readers like fread(), but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have encountered this before. Can be very tricky. Try a specialized CSV reader.:

```
library(readr)
data <- read_csv(file="train.csv")
```

This should do it.

Comment: Worked fine. Brilliant!